# how many valid pass words are there?

Tags: combinatorics

Students are required to create 6-character long passwords to access the library. The letters must be from lowercase letters or digits. Each password must contain at least two lowercase letters, at least one digit and contains no repeated digits. How many valid passwords are there?

I came up with some steps but was unsure if it is correct.

1. 2 letters and 4 digits: $\binom{6}{2} \times 26^2 \times \binom{6}{4} \times 10 \times 9 \times 8 \times 7$
2. 3 letters and 3 digits: $\binom{6}{3} \times 26^3 \times \binom{6}{3} \times 10 \times 9 \times 8$
3. repeat until 5 letters and 1 digits and add all the answers together

is this the right method?

Comment: The second binomial coefficient is not needed. The places already get secured for the digits when you select the places for letters. Also, the 3rd point should be "repeat until 5 letters ..."

Comment: For example: ab1234 and ab4321. Both of them are different so won't the second binomial coefficient ensure it calculates the different positions for the digits?

Comment: Suppose $\binom{6}{2}$ selects the first two places for letters. Now, $10 \times 9 \times 8 \times 7$, will take care of forming all 4 digit numbers with non-repeated digits.

Comment: +1 to your question for good work shown.  Your analysis contains a natural mistake which the comments of @bigbang have responded to.  Going forward for future similar problems, with intuition playing such a large role in the analysis, sanity-checking is a powerful weapon.  It has two forms: [1] Write a program in Java, C, Python, or whatever programming language that you are comfortable with to manually enumerate, to verify your analysis. [2] When you develop a formula, manually check if the formula works for smaller examples (e.g. 4 character password, letters a,b,c,d,e only, #'s 1,2,3 only).

Comment: i get it now, thank you!!